# how to print a complete div without page break

Tags: html, printing, cross-browser, page-break, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [page-break-inside:avoid equivalent for Firefox and/or IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401229/page-break-insideavoid-equivalent-for-firefox-and-or-ie)

Referring to this question [CSS Printing: Avoiding cut-in-half DIVs between pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907680/css-printing-avoiding-cut-in-half-divs-between-pages)

```
page-break-inside: avoid;
```

This property is not working in Firefox. What is its equivalent for Firefox?

Comment: `page-break-inside` is a specific CSS2 tag for Opera browser... you might need much more than Firefox. You have no control on how the user prints as that's hardware and from a webpage, you can't access hardware settings, you will need to use a 3rd party component to handle this.

Comment: Maybe try `page-break-before : always`? (Yes, this might put an unnecessary break, but perhaps that's better than a page break in the middle for your specific case.)

Comment: @Programer http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/page-break-inside only Opera and IE8 or above, and even that it's buggy.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks , page-break-before:always it works

Comment: @nnnnnn it's fine but major problem is this is printing 1 div per page :(

Comment: Dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401229/page-break-insideavoid-equivalent-for-firefox-and-or-ie