# Page Breaks in Tables for Printing Not Working

Tags: css, printing, twitter-bootstrap

I have a rather large table that is to be printed and I want to ensure that page breaks do not occure within a row.

I used the following CSS but this does not seem to work:

`tr {page-break-inside: avoid }`

This is recommended everywhere but does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: On the <tr>?  It is a kinda bogus element.  Try it on the table instead?  How much paper you wasted so far? ;)

Comment: Try setting that on the <td> instead

Comment: Also, FireFox seems to lack support.  See compatibility: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/page-break-inside

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401229/page-break-insideavoid-equivalent-for-firefox-and-or-ie)